# jQuery Simple Dialog Events

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a simpledialog2 box, its fully functional but im trying to work out a way to call a function when its been loaded.

For example i have

```
$('<div>').simpledialog2({
    mode : 'blank',
    animate : false,
    transition : 'none',
    // dialogAllow : true,
    // dialogForce : true,
    headerText : 'Statement Metadata',
    blankContent : "HTML HERE"

});
```

After HTML HERE has been loaded what event is fired? Or how can i call javascript once the simpledialog2 is fuly ready?

Similar to pageshow event handler...

Comment: callbackOpen - Type:Function Default:false Modes:all
Function to run when the dialog opens.  So can't you use .simpledialog2({ callbackOpen: function() {alert('ok')} });

Comment: Veyr good answer will give it a try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
$('<div>').simpledialog2({
    mode : 'blank',
    animate : false,
    transition : 'none',
    // dialogAllow : true,
    // dialogForce : true,
    headerText : 'Statement Metadata',
    blankContent : "HTML HERE",
    callbackOpen: function() {
         var me = this;
         alert('opened');
         setTimeout(function() {me.close();},2000);
    }
});
```

Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/ykHTa/62/

Comment: How can i close the dialog2 box using javascript ? Without using a button

Comment: inside the callBackOpen function you can probably call this.close(), I cant try cause I don't have a test case.